# What exactly is an AWS "Edge Location"?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I've heard rumours that Amazon is launching two edge locations near me, but it's not completely obvious what these actually are.

I've googled for a basic definition but this doesn't really clarify.

Are they just edge servers for their CDN?

Comment: Did you try googling "aws edge locations" ? I'm pretty sure it'll answer your questions.

Comment: As stated, i did Google and it's not completely clear.

Comment: It doesn't say that it's "edge servers for their CDN" but rather *used* by their CDN. The definition "An edge location is where end users access services located at AWS" is pretty simple and straightforward. Can you be more specific with your question ? (meaning, which part of this definition requires clarifications)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what "access services located at AWS" means in this context. Is the edge just a way to speed up these services' frontends, or the services themselves. i.e. if i want to use EC2 currently, the latency is horrific. Will this mean lower-latency access to EC2?

Comment: "access services located at AWS" - means exactly what it says, access all kinds of different AWS services (and there are hundreds of then as you probably already know). It might help improve latency to *some* services but not necessarily. What would *really* solve your latency issues is if aws deploy a new region in Africa: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: @infomaniac can you cite the specific document that mentions these new edge locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS Glossary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glos-chap.html#E) states that an edge location is:
A site that CloudFront uses to cache copies of your content for faster delivery to users at any location.

[From AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=91845): "An AWS region contains two or more availability zones. Each zone is basically a separate datacenter, and provides low latency connectivity to all other zones in the region. Your resources, such as EC2 instances, reside in the region of your choice. The AWS regions are isolated from each other, but you can seamlessly manage resources in different availability zones within the same region.

Edge locations serve requests for CloudFront and Route 53. CloudFront is a content delivery network, while Route 53 is a DNS service. Requests going to either one of these services will be routed to the nearest edge location automatically. This allows for low latency no matter where the end user is located.'

Comment: S3 Transfer Acceleration traffic and API Gateway endpoint traffic also use the AWS Edge Network.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier/simplier to think about it as "edge server for their CDN". It will NOT speed up ssh access, RDB connection, connection between EC2 and RDB etc.

Also, I suppose it is used to access AWS console and other services like that but it is just guess.

Answer (score 0):

An edge location is where end users access services located at AWS. They are located in most of the major cities around the world and are specifically used by CloudFront (CDN) to distribute content to end user to reduce latency. It is like a frontend for the service we access which are located in the AWS cloud.